Why is failing to retrieve DICOM tag values?
I am using the following code to retrieve values from a DICOM file.  All values contained string data types:
var item1 = dicomDataset.GetSingleValueOrDefault<string>(DicomTag.MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID, "");
if (item1 == "")
{
    item1 = "(not set)";
}
Console.WriteLine($"SOPInstanceUID: {item1}");  //DOES NOT WORK


var sopUID = dicomDataset.GetSingleValueOrDefault<string>(DicomTag.SOPInstanceUID, "");
if (sopUID == "")
{
    sopUID = "(not set)";
}
Console.WriteLine($"SOPInstanceUID: {sopUID}"); //DOES NOT WORK


var stuUID = dicomDataset.GetSingleValueOrDefault<string>(DicomTag.StudyInstanceUID, "");
if (stuUID == "")
{
    stuUID = "(not set)";
}
Console.WriteLine($"StudyInstanceUID: {stuUID}");



var serInst = dicomDataset.GetSingleValueOrDefault<string>(DicomTag.SeriesInstanceUID, "");
if (serInst == "")
{
    serInst = "(not set)";
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"SeriesInstanceUID: {serInst}");
    
    
    var forUID = dicomDataset.GetSingleValueOrDefault<string>(DicomTag.FrameOfReferenceUID, "");
    if (forUID == "")
    {
        forUID = "(not set)";
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"FrameOfReferenceUID: {forUID}");

There are two values that cannot be retrieved (DicomTag.MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID and SOPInstanceUID); however, the rest of the values are returned successfully.
Any ideas what is going on here?  Many thanks in advance.

Usually, you should not find the MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID in the dicomdataset. The MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID is stored in Group 0002, which is a kind of header of DicomFiles.
So if the sourc is a DicomFile, then you will find the MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID in dicomFile.FileMeataInfo.GetSingleValueOrDefault<string>(DicomTag.MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID, "") and all the other tags in dicomFile.Dataset.GetSingleValueOrDefault.....
If the sourc is a Dataset received via network in a StoreSCP service, then you will not find the MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID at all. Fo-dicom will add it when you store the dataset to a file.
The way, you access the SOPInstanceUID is perfectly correct. The only explanation is, that your dicomdataset is not a valid dicom file.

Great explanation-Many thannks
